# Highlight html td by diffrent color when cell value is greater than specific value

Tags: javascript

I try to change the row color when it's `td cell` value is `greater than 10`, nevertheless at the moment all rows become highlight when hover is done on `Darksalmon` color and no `Red` when `value is > 10`. What i am doing wrong?

**Additional question:** My html table has 5 columns, i do not want last one to be highlited. How to exclude such column?

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr {
        background: #fff;
    }

        tr:hover {
            background: darksalmon;
        }
</style>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Highlight(row) {
        if(document.getElementById("price").value > 10)
        {
            document.getElementById(row).style.background = 'Red';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById(row).removeAttribute("style");
            document.getElementById(row).onMouseOver = function () { this.className = "hover"; }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Html:**

```
<table>
      <tr id="row1" onmouseover="javascript:Highlight('row1');">
          <td id="price"></td>
      </tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong:

HTML:

You should close the table tag `</table>`.
Don't give your table rows and table cells an id. Give your table body or table an idea for example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
const tableBody = document.getElementById("tbody"); // get your table body or table if you don't want a table body
    const rows = tableBody.getElementsByTagName("tr"); // get all your table rows inside your table body

    // loop through all your tr elements
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        // here it is probably best to get the td element but because there is only one column there is no need for this.
        // if there are more then 1 columns get the td element like this  const td = rows[i].firstElementChild; if it is
        // the first otherwise give them a class and get them with getElementsByClassName[0] on the rows[i]

        // try to parse the innerText of the td or tr element to an integer (Number) because if there is text this will throw an exception

        try {
            // if price > 10 make background color of row red otherwise darkSalmon

            if (parseInt(rows[i].innerText) > 10) {
                rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
            else {
                rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "darksalmon";
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }

        //if you want to do this on mousover you can add event listeners per row
        rows[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
            try {
                // if price > 10 make background color of row red otherwise darkSalmon

                if (parseInt(rows[i].innerText) > 10) {
                    rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
                }
                else {
                    rows[i].style.backgroundColor = "darksalmon";
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            }
        });

        //if you want to set the background color back on default when your mouse leaves the tr do this
        rows[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = null;
        });
    }
```

I hope this is detailed enough for you, otherwise I suggest reading some basic tutorials on w3schools or a platform like that.

Comment: i enclosed table correctly, just copy/past typo, i will check later on. Why not to give id to what you mentioned? I;ve seen lot of stack asnwers providing id to either tr/table/td. an you explain furthermore?

Comment: An id should be unique.  Give them a class then. If you would have more then 100 rows would you want to write sepperate code for every one of the rows?